# Regular non-low energy bluetooth for IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

Ok, so I can't get my app to connect with a peripheral using bluetooth low-energy(my app is installed on an iPhone 5s and I have LightBlue installed on an iPhone 4S, simulating a peripheral.  I also have light blue installed on the 5s, simulating a central, to verify that the two can connect and they do.) I have verified that the centralManager is instantiating and the State is powered on. So, my question is, is regular bluetooth still a viable option? Can I just use the GameKit API and go that route?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you taken a look at multipeer connectivity?

Comment: Nope. Never heard of it. Will look into it. Thamks.